# React-native - expo cli - npm install new project error message - Unable_to_get_issuer_cert_locally

Tags: windows, react-native, npm-install

Creating react native expo cli using the below commands,
expo init myproj
cd myproj
npm install

facing the below issues,
npm err errno Unable_to_get_issuer_cert_locally
request to https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.4.tar.gz

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgWoZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My IT Team, providing access to the https://expo.io/ in the firewall, now I am able to access expo login and expo init also.